# How to make a view transparent to show home page phone?

Tags: react-native, transparency, homescreen

Is there a way to make a view transparent to show the home page of the phone in react native? I tried:

```
backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
```

But it didn't work. I want to be able to view the home page when my app is running and show elements on it. Is this possible?

Here is my code so far:

```
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'transparent',flex:1}}>
             <Text>hello cruel world</Text>
        </View>

     )
 }
```

But this code is not working.
this is a image about what i want to happend
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrSkJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

React native creates Views based on the what the OS allows you. Android started to run the apps on a white background (previously you were able to theme a transparent background) but iOS never allowed you to run an app 'over' the device screen. Hope it helps--

Comment: thanks but i need it just for android... is this possible at all?

Comment: From Android 5 and on, it is not possible. There are some app launcher replacement which says they can allows you but I haven't tried. Those launchers replace the OS launcher to avoid to set a white card under the app when it starts. Walter--